# How to avoid querystring modification in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net web application.I am sending user a link on email id.When user click on that link,web page get open.I am passing querystring to that page.

```
Like : htttp://localhost:7899/Test.aspx?Id=2
```

I don't want user to do changes in querystring (id) Id.How to do that?

Comment: You can't. A user can always change the querystring. If you want to prevent tampering you have to send a token along with the mail and validate that when the user clicks that link along with the email adress the token was send to.

Comment: you can't prevent changes - a client can request whatever URL it likes. What you can do is check for unwanted values and either discard them or throw an exception, depending on whether it's still possible to complete the request with the information provided. And that's actually a slightly separate issue from the issue of whether the user is _authorised_ to request the specific resource. e.g. if they can access `Test.aspx?Id=2` but not `Test.aspx?Id=3` then you need a way for the user to confirm their identity when accessing your site.